# jQuery: зависимость высота от контейнера

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать что если высота `.container` больше высоты `.sidebar` - то высота `.sidebar` зависит от `.container`.

Я просто только начинаю учить JavaScript, и пока что не совсем понимаю синтаксис этого языка, хотя что говорить вообще не знаю пока что JavaScript.

```
if($(".container").height() > $(".right").height()) {
    $('.right').height($('.container').height());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первой строке `.container`, во второй - `.conteiner`. Опечатка, потому и не работает.

Comment: Я Слепой, Спасибо ))), блин как не заметил....

Answer (score 0):

Если только учишь JS, то не используй jQuery или другие библиотеки - только будешь путать что и как.
А решение где-то так:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container');
var right = document.querySelector('.right');
// Сохранили элементы удобства ради
if(parseInt(getComputedStyle(right, null).height) > (cHeight = parseInt(getComputedStyle(container, null).height))){ // Если высота .right больше чем высота .container
 right.style.height = cHeight + 'px'; // Делаем .right равным .container
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет, и за пример кода, помогло.

Comment: Роман, у Вас логически правильный код, только опечатка в селекторе, поэтому не работало.